# Laravel: How to send emails using sendmail

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-mail

I am using Laravel 7 and I want to send an email using **sendemail** driver using Laravel Mail Facade because it worked when I used php mail function but I want to use the Laravel Mail Facade.

This is my .env file email configration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL='/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
```

And this is my default mail in config/mail.php

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    ],
    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],
    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],
    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],
```

what is the right configuration how make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [How to send email with Laravel using sendmail?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-send-email-with-laravel-using-sendmail) and you will get full idea.

Comment: I've added MAIL_HOST and MAIL_PORT but still no mail being sent

Comment: can you please give your .env configuration related to mail ? Adding to question is preferable.

Comment: I've updated the email configration in the question

Comment: What is www.alrahden.com ? is this your site? If you don't want to put host as your site. If you sendmail through gmail set it as in my above link.

Comment: yes, it is the site. I want to use the sendmail that is installed on the shared hosting for the site

Comment: what ever way you will do your hosting that's not problem if you want to send mail then you want to use mailing engine like gmail so something like. so you will change the think like in link it will work.

Comment: well, I don't want to use gmail service, I thought sendmail sends mails without the need for other providors. I will try with the domain email to check if it will work with their email because it will be shown as the sender,

Answer (score 3):

From your question I can't exactly see how far you've gotten in the proces, so I'll attempt to explain it for you.

You need to create an email using Artisan:

```
php artisan make:mail MailName
```

Mails in Laravel are basically just views, so in the `build()` function of your mail, reference a view like so:

```
$this->view('folder.view');
```

You need to configure an email-address that the email is sent from, you can do that in the Mail file:

```
$this->from('youremail@domain.com');
```

Or you can set one globally in your `mail.php` file:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

To send the mail, use the line below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; // Put this at the top of your controller

Mail::to($recipient)->send(new MailName);
```

If you're using variables in your view, you need to pass them in, you can do that like so:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; // Put this at the top of your controller
    
Mail::to($recipient)->send(new MailName($variables));
```

For other information such as CC, attachments etc, see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail).

Comment: thank you for explaining the proccess, And I can assure you that I've read the docs and made them all.
thats why I think my error is in the configuration of the mail. But I can't yet know whats wrong

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

```php
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class X
{
    public function sendEmail() : bool
    {
        try {
            $mailable = new Mailable();

            $mailable
                ->from('hello@example.com')
                ->to('hello@example.com')
                ->subject('test subject')
                ->html('my first message');

            $result = Mail::send($mailable);
            return true;
        } catch (\Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException $exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```